# ::content polyfill for VanillaJS Templates and Custom Elements

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

It seems that Polymer's

```
polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host #myId' }
```

Does not work (in IE) for VanillaJS `<template>`s and Custom Elements.

For `<polymer-element>` it works fine: http://codepen.io/robdodson/pen/FokEw/, but for some reason when I try to do the same with native JS it doesn't

```
<template>
  <style>
    polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host h1' }
    ::content h1 {
    color: red;
    }
  </style>
  ..ShadowDOM stuff..
  <content></content>
</template>

<my-element>
  <h1>Hello World, I'm red content of Custom Element</h1>
</my-element>
```

http://codepen.io/tomalec/pen/apqgr

`shim-shadowdom` attribute also does not help.

Is there any workaround, or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shimming styles is something polymer.js (the sugaring) does for you automatically. It inlines stylesheets -> `<style>` in an element, shims those styles, and adds them to the document head under the polyfill.

If you're using the vanilla stuff, you have to do the shimming manually and adding manually. If you include the `shim-shadowdom` attribute on a `<style>` or stylesheet, this should really just work but there's still some overlap between polymer.js and platform.js.

The solution!...in `createdCallback()`:

```
if (Platform.ShadowCSS) {
  var style = template.querySelector('style');

  var cssText = Platform.ShadowCSS.shimCssText(
      style.textContent, 'my-element');
  Platform.ShadowCSS.addCssToDocument(cssText);
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/xadocene/3/edit

Note, I'm checking `Platform.ShadowCSS` because it doesn't exist under native Shadow DOM and there's no need to do the extra work.

See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#manualshim for more.

Comment: Did that change to `WebComponents.ShadowCSS.shimStyling(template.content, 'my-element')` in newer versions? ([discussion in this issue](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/140)) Querying for the style element returns `null` for me but `shimStyling` on the template seems to work.